# Java Swing Worker causes GUI freeze

Tags: java, swing

Hello there I am trying to implement a chat  using RMI. The algorithm is the following: both the shared RMI object and the clients have a String variable for the last typed message. Whenever a client types a message, the message from the shared RMI object updates(messageRMI=messageClient). If a client doensn't have its last message equal with the message from the RMI Object, the last message will be automatically typed in the jTextPane.

This is the swing worker:

```
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground()
            throws Exception {
            byte[] the_image;
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (connected) {
                    try {
                        remote = (I) Naming.lookup("rmi://" + jTextFieldAddress.getText() + "/Niemand23");
                        switch (remote.refresh_chat(last_message)) {
                            case 0:
                                last_message = remote.last_message();
                                jTextPane1.getStyledDocument().insertString(jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength(), "\n ", null);
                                if (remote.hasImage()) {
                                    the_image = remote.client_image();
                                    formatC = new ImageIcon(the_image);
                                    jTextPane1.insertIcon(formatC);
                                } else {
                                    jTextPane1.insertIcon(noImageIcon);
                                }
                                jTextPane1.getStyledDocument()
                                    .insertString(jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength(), "\n " + remote.last_message(), style);
                                jTextPane1.getStyledDocument().insertString(jTextPane1.getDocument().getLength(), "\n", null);
                        }
                    } catch (NotBoundException | MalformedURLException | RemoteException | BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The worker should check the condition every second. The big problem is that whenever a client types a message, the GUI from the second one freezes. I've tried everything but no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [SwingWorker javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) you'll see you should not be making direct changes to the Swing components in your `doInBackground()` method.

Rather, you should implement the `process()` method and use the `publish()` method in `doInBackground()`. For specifics, look at the [publish method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish(V...)).

In your case this would entail switching your `SwingWorker<Void, Void>` to `SwingWorker<Void,String>` and `publish()` each message as you receive it. Your `process(String...s)` method would then populate the `jTextPane1` with the incoming messages.

Give this a try and see how it works.

**ETA**: Also, do you need to be performing the naming lookup in every runthrough of your loop? The address isn't changing, is it?

Comment: I tried it, still not working, I also noticed that if I put Thread.sleep(150) before every code to insert the message into the jTextPane it works for a while(8 message exchanges) and then the GUI freezes again. I tried almost everything and I am really starting to give up. It's annoying because it won't even give me an error so I could know what's wrong.

Comment: So [get a stack trace](http://www.software-architect.net/articles/creating-java-stack-traces.html) and see where things get stuck.

Comment: If `connected` gets set to `false`, this code would find itself in an infinite loop. I have no idea where `connected` is coming from or what would change it (you didn't provide that part of the code), but is this possible? Perhaps you want your loop to be `while (connected) { ... }` (and then get rid of the `if` statement entirely)?

Comment: connected is a boolean variable which is initialy set to false. When a client logs in, the variable is set to true

Comment: So there's no way for it to be set to false again? Of course there is, otherwise you wouldn't check it. You should consider my suggestion, at least. Did you get the stack trace?

Comment: well I am checking it because it has to grab the RMI address which must be first typed on the login panel otherwise I get RMI error at the beginning (I am using a JTabbedPane-one of its panes is where I have the jTextPane)

Comment: So did you get the stack trace?